# Get Full Path for Unsaved File to attach to Outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a copy of a worksheet and email only the copy as an attachment. It will not attach the ActiveWorkbook, and I think it's because it's never saved, so it's in a temporary location.

If I use `Activeworkbook.Path`, it gives the file name, and not the full path.
If I use `ThisWorkbook.Path` it gives the path of the workbook I created the copy from, and not the copy itself.

```vb
Sub DemandEM() 
Dim OutApp As Object 
Dim Outmail As Object 
Dim Subject As String 
Dim Body As String
Dim Attachment As String

Subject = "DMND NP" & Sheets("Loading").Cells(4, 2).Value 
Body = "Please see attachment for NP" & Sheets("Loading").Cells(4, 2).Value
Sheets("Demand Input").Copy
Attachment = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
OutApp.Session.Logon 
Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Outmail
    .to = "ABC@123.com"
    .Subject = Subject
    .Body = Body
    .Attachments.Add (Attachment)
    .Display 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Save the file in for example the Temp folder?

Comment: You can access the temp folder with `environ("temp")`

Comment: An unsaved workbook does not have a path. You must save it somewhere and supply its full name.

Answer (score 1):

### Outlook: Send Newly Created Workbook

- This will save your created one-sheet workbook in the `ThisWorkbook's` path under the name `Demand Input.xlsx` and close it. After the remaining outlook code, it will delete the file.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DemandEM()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim Outmail As Object
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim Body As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    Subject = "DMND NP" & Sheets("Loading").Cells(4, 2).Value
    Body = "Please see attachment for NP" & Sheets("Loading").Cells(4, 2).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Demand Input").Copy ' create new one-sheet workbook
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        dFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Demand Input.xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        .Save dFilePath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With Outmail
        .to = "ABC@123.com"
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = Body
        .Attachments.Add dFilePath
        .Display
    End With

    ' If you want to keep the file, out-comment the following line.
    Kill dFilePath
    
End Sub
```